# Are React Native super apps allowed in Play store or App store?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I would like to create an app consisting of a main application that will be available on the Play / App Store. Additionally, there will be several mini app bundles hosted on an S3 bucket or another cloud storage service.

These mini apps will be linked to the main app using Module Federations. When a user attempts to access any of these mini apps, they will be downloaded into the main app, allowing the user to access them.

However, I have concerns about whether downloading separate bundles onto a user's device at a later time would be permitted by the app review policies of iOS and Android.

**In summary**, *I want to build a main app on the Play Store with linked mini app bundles stored in the cloud, but I'm unsure if the ability to download these bundles later would comply with iOS and Android app review policies.*

Reference URL :

1. https://www.callstack.com/blog/step-by-step-guide-to-super-app-development

Flow diagram :

[image: High level flow diagram]

[image: Example app]